# After installing bulma through NPM, how can I refer it in my project

Tags: npm, bulma

I have pulled in bulma in my project through  :

```
$ npm install bulma
```

After that, how can I refer to it in my pages. I really don't know how to work with npm, so please can you guide me. Do I have to refer to it in my js by saying: 
 `import bulma from 'bulma'` or require it, I don't know where my files are. That means I don't know where are they located.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can find the final css build at `projectName/node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css`.

Chances are you're using a file loader with webpack and similar. If, for example in a Vue project, you have that, then you can use import syntax:

`import 'bulma/css/bulma.css'`

within your js. This works because having `import [xyz from] 'xyz'` will look at `projectName/node_modules/xyz`, and in the case of a css file, it's as simple as that!

If you do not have that installed, you need to find a way to send it over to the client. Just copy `projectName/node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css` into a file, maybe `bulma.css`, in either an `assets` or `public` or whatever you use, then fetch it like you'd fetch any css file within the html: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bulma.css">`

Comment: In Vue.js as an example, I can just use `import Bulma from 'bulma'` in main.js and it works.

Answer (score 6):

`@import "../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css";`

If you have a `main.css` file for your project or something similar to that, you can add the above line inside your `main.css` file. This will import the default `bulma.css` file located inside your project's path `node_modules/bulma/css/` after you have installed bulma via npm.

NOTE: you must include your `main.css` file( or something similar) inside your `index.html` as a static import if you chose to go this way.
For that you need to have something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

I prefer this since bulma is a CSS framework, I think it's best to keep the stylesheets linked with each other.

Comment: This works great in Visual Studio Code when you also enable the extension "Live Server" to run at the same time. No need to install and configure Webpack for something thats not robust, especially if you simply want a do a crash course with Bulma alone.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It's CSS only.

Bulma is a CSS framework.

So you can add it just in your `index.html` like a normal css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your/bulma/path/bulma.css />
```

Edit: You have installed `bulma` through the **nodejs** environment with the package manager `npm` so you must have a directory called **node_modules** and inside the `bulma` directory.

Comment: What if I'm using it in a back-end framework. What is the bulma path for it ?

Comment: @d3cypher I edited the answer although I don't understand what you mean with the back-end framework since this has to do with the client side, it's css. Hope I helped you!

Comment: @d3cypher Was my answer useful? you found it?

Comment: As he mentioned, you can add the `link` in your static index file

Comment: Is this practice used in production level as well or is it just for development purpose?

Answer (score 2):

That is really unevident. If you want to get `bulma` work with `fontawesome5` via `npm`, minimum working deps (for now) are:

```
npm i -S bulma @fortawesome/fontawesome @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid
```

then needed to be initialized like this:

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'
import solid from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid'
import 'bulma/css/bulma.css'

fontawesome.library.add(solid)
```

More details can be found here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Vue and in the end I solved it thanks to this [link](https://alligator.io/vuejs/css-frameworks-vuejs/). For Bulma you just need to run:

> $ npm install bulma

After `npm install`, your files should be located under `node_modules` folder.

For Bulma, check that you have a folder `bulma` under `node_modules`, then you can import bulma css framework in your main.js file as follows: `import "./../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css";`

**Note**: even if on the [link](https://alligator.io/vuejs/css-frameworks-vuejs/) I provided they suggest the full path to bulma this is not a good practice as @Omkar pointed out, so I ended up importing bulma as follows: `import "bulma/css/bulma.css";`

Comment: do not suggest beginners to use `../../` relative paths. Using webpack, you can use aliases

Comment: Do you mean using `@/../node_modules/...` I can edit my answer if this is what you suggest

Comment: No, look at relative paths vs aliases. Node js automatically picks up node modules, so you dont have to provide a complete path. Either ways, even if its not from node modules, its recommended to use `aliases` provided by module bundlers to reduce the nesting of paths. The practice of nesting will end up adding lot of unreadable paths when the app will grow large.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Answer: CSS Preprocessing**

I'm posting a somewhat **indirect** way to answer the question. I came here looking to see how I could use rendered SASS in my main `app.js` (in my case, for use in a *pug.js* template).

The answer is: use a **CSS pre-processor**. In this minimal example, I'll use [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass).

**0. Install:**

```sh
npm install node-sass
npm install bulma
```

**1. Create an inherited style**

`mystyles.scss`:

```js
@charset "utf-8";
@import "node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass"; // <--- Check and make sure this file is here after installing Bulma
```

This will inherit styles from the Bulma installation, but override those styles with what you place here.

**2. Build the CSS**

`app.js`:

```js
const nsass = require("node-sass");

const rendered_style = nsass.renderSync({ // <---- This call is synchronous!
  file: "./mystyles.scss",
});
```

Here, node-sass is processing the `.scss` file into a [Result](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#result-object) object that has CSS buffer. Note that `node-sass` has an asynchronous call (`sass.render()`) as well, if needed.

**3. Use the CSS**

The buffer containing the CSS is now available at `rendered_style.css`

```js
console.write(rendered_style.css)
```

**--Notes--**

The benefit of the SASS approach is that it unlocks [Customization](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/concepts/), which is what makes Bulma powerful!

Keep in mind that if `app.js` is your entry point, the CSS will be rendered every time you run the server. If your styles aren't changing frequently, it may be best to write it out to a file. You can see more on this approach in the [Bulma Documenation I adapted this from](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/).

Answer (score -3):

declaring this in the index.html file worked for me.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.0/css/bulma.min.css">
```

In React, we have to declare this in the same html file where the root of the app is present.

Comment: If the OP has installed already using npm. He probably does not want to pull in Bulma using CDN.