# How to use bulma css that was installed from npm?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, bulma

I installed express from express-generator by `express --view=pug --css=sass --git`. After this i maked `npm init` and `npm install bulma`. I followed guide. When I tryed to import styles with `@import "../../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/variables"` - no errors, and all looks fine. But, when i tryed to import bulma with `@import "../../node_modules/bulma/bulma"` my css dont want to compile. In the first i thinked that i made wrong way when import, and thas why i installed WebStorm. But all looks done well.

Code of my error in CLI

```
GET / 304 309.700 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 500 34.217 ms - 939
RangeError: Invalid status code: 1
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:195:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (D:\websites\chat\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:159:8)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:621:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\websites\chat\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:205:10)
    at done (D:\websites\chat\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:956:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (D:\websites\chat\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:422:12)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (D:\websites\chat\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:465:11)
    at View.render (D:\websites\chat\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
    at tryRender (D:\websites\chat\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
```

Comment: In which file you try to import bulma?

Comment: `styles.sass` that was maked by [Express generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After installing bulma through NPM, how can I refer it in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018089/after-installing-bulma-through-npm-how-can-i-refer-it-in-my-project)